# Entity Framework Code First: map list of ids to entity using reference table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, ef-code-first, mapping

Let's say I have an existing entity EmailNotification and another entity User. I want my EmailNotification to contain a list of users that it can be sent to. As I see it achievable from database perspective is that we create an additional table like following:

```
CREATE TABLE UserGroup (UserGroupID INT NOT NULL, UserID INT NOT NULL)
```

and add a UserGroupID column into EmailNotification.

However, the problem is that I can't think of a way how I can do this using EntityFramework Code First approach, so that I can have a list of Users inside EmailNotification. I want something like

```
EmailNotification
{
  public virtual IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

but I don't see how can I do the mentioned mapping using EntityFramework (preferably set it from DbContext, not FluentAPI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this case you have many-to-many relation:

**MODELS:**

```
public class EmailNotification
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    //other stuff...
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{   
    public int ID { get; set; }
    //other stuff...
    public virtual ICollection<EmailNotification> EmailNotifications { get; set; }
}
```

So, EF will implicitley create table: User2EmailNotification with columns: UserID and EmailNotificationID.

> P.S. If you, all the same, want to create table UserGroup, it will be
>   hard (or not comfortable) to access Users from `EmailNotification`
>   class, instead you will should to declare `UserGroup` property inside
>   this class, so relation between Users and EmailNotifications will be
>   indirect.

Comment: I have thought of this approach but I don't really need User->EmailNotification relationship in my case. Is it possible to create some grouping table that would just contain a group id and a group of users for each group id so that it can be used in this case and in some future ones?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but at this case you can't declare EmailNotification->Users, instead it will be EmailNotification->UserGroup, so you should choose between these variants.

Answer (score 2):

In nutsell what you need I think is to create many to many relation between EmailNotification and User, if the case is that one user can be included in a lot of notifications and one notification can include a lot of users then you need following construct

```
    public class User
    {

        public int UserId{ get; set; } /*your properties*/  

        public virtual ICollection<EmailNotification> Courses { get; set; }
    }
    public class EmailNotification
    {

        public int EmailNotificationId{ get; set; } /*your properties*/  

        public virtual ICollection<User> Courses { get; set; }
    }
```

and to customize many to many table creation you can override OnModelCreating

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany<EmailNotification>(s => s.EmailNotification)
            .WithMany(c => c.User)
            .Map(cs =>
                    {
                        cs.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                        cs.MapRightKey("EmailNotificationId");
                        cs.ToTable("UserEmailNotifications");
                    });
    }
```